# Why does my Nexus One power off with 15% power remaining?

Tags: nexus-one, battery

Once my Nexus One's remaining power drops to 15%, it automatically powers off. On turning it back on again, it reports that it's now on 0% power.

Do all Nexus Ones behave like this, or is it just mine?

Possibly relevant apps I have installed are:

- BatteryTime Lite. This gives a percentage power in the notification bar. I thought it might be mis-reporting, but the value it reports always seems to match what the phone reports in Settings > About Phone > Battery Use
- JuiceDefender. This turns the data connection on and off to try to preserve battery.

I can't see settings in either of these that would turn the phone off at 15% power.

I'm currently on Android 2.3.4, but I think this happened on earlier versions too.

Answer (score 7):

Probably your battery does not hold as much charge as it used to, and so your phone's estimate of 15% is incorrect; the battery is actually almost dead.  To get a more accurate reading, try [the following](http://www.nexusoneforum.net/forum/nexus-one-faq-how-tos/5625-calibrate-your-battery.html):

> ## RECALIBRATION:
>
> A recalibration is mostly needed, when dealing with different kernels (ROOT!). Most custom recovery images provide the option "battery stats wipe" under the menue "Wipe".
>
> Here is how ya do it!
>
> 1. Enter Recovery Mode
> 2. do a full nandroid (or nandroid+ext) backup
> 3. Enter "Wipe"-Menue
> 4. do "Battery stats wipe"
> 5. reboot
> 6. Calibrate the battery by completely draining it until the phone completely shuts itself off.
> 7. Turn the phone on again and let it shut itself off one more time.
> 8. Then charge your phone while it is off for over 8 hours.
> 9. This will fully charge the battery so that when the Android is turned on, it now sees the battery as full.

Answer (score 0):

> Do all Nexus Ones behave like this, or is it just mine?

Mine does not do that, I cannot speak for any others though.

If I had to guess it sounds like for some reason the OS is tracking the battery health incorrectly so when it reports 15% the battery is actually all the way dead. When you try to turn it back on it fixes the reporting and (correctly) reports it as 0% and then probably turns back off a short time thereafter if it isn't plugged in. I think it is probably unrelated to the 3rd party battery monitor app that you use. Are you running the stock OS or did you flash a ROM onto it? If you are running stock the only suggestion I have is factory reset and hope that it is fixed after that. If you are running a 3rd party ROM it is likely a bug in the ROM that is affecting your device.

Edit: I would try @Matthew's suggestion before you resort to factory reset. That seems like it could be what is happening to your device.

Comment: Certainly not all but it happens from time to time, on any kind of Android phone. See e.g. [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-6/477924-10-battery-phone-turns-off.html) or [this](http://androidforums.com/threads/low-battery-phone-turns-off-at-15.431871/) or [this](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/phone-is-shutting-off-when-battery-is-at-15.144479/) discussion. (My Nexus 4 also started doing it recently.)